# Не могу подключится к базе данных. В чем может быть проблема?

Tags: sql

Выдает вот такую ошибку. Сервер МС СКЛ 2000.
************** Текст исключения **************

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: При установлении соединения с SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения. (provider: Поставщик TCP, error: 0 - Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение.)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean withFailover)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean withFailover)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   в Functions.FillComboBox() в c:\users\accfo\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\testdb\testdb\functions.h:строка 45
   в testDB.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) в c:\users\accfo\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\testdb\testdb\form1.h:строка 115
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Вот мой код :

```
#pragma once

#include"ClassNames.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace Data;
using namespace Data::SqlClient;
using namespace std;

ref class Functions
{
public:
    Functions(void);

    SqlConnection^ conn;
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder^ connStringBuilder;

    void ConnectToDB()
    {
        connStringBuilder = gcnew SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        connStringBuilder->DataSource = "192.168.1.50,1433";
        connStringBuilder->InitialCatalog = "testDB";
        connStringBuilder->IntegratedSecurity = true;
        connStringBuilder->UserID = "Justdark";
        connStringBuilder->Password = "2250602";

        conn = gcnew SqlConnection(Convert::ToString(connStringBuilder));
    }

public: ListBox::ObjectCollection^ FillComboBox()
        {
            ConnectToDB();
            ClassNames^ n = gcnew ClassNames();
            ListBox^ ListWithNames = gcnew ListBox();


            String^ cmdText = "SELECT * FROM testTable";
            SqlCommand^ cmd = gcnew SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
            conn->Open();

            SqlDataReader^ reader = cmd->ExecuteReader();

            while(reader->Read())
            {
                n->ID = Convert::ToInt32(reader["ID"]->ToString());
                n->Name = (reader["Name"]->ToString());

                ListWithNames->Items->Add(String::Format("{0} - {1}", n->ID, n->Name));
            }



            return ListWithNames->Items;
        }
};
```

Comment: 1. Не уверен, но вроде бы в случае указания порта протокол надо указывать явно: connStringBuilder->DataSource = "tcp:192.168.1.50,1433"; 2. Проверьте сервер - на каких портах работает: динамических или статических; 3. проверьте файрвол на сервере - должны быть разрешены порты 1433, 1434. Для начала...

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка здесь "192.168.1.50,1433". Порт указывается через двоеточие.